# Submonoid and abelian monoid

Tags: semigroups, monoid

Prove that - **For any abelian monoid (M,*) ,the set of idempotent elements of M forms a submonoid** ....

I can relate between idempotent elements and abelian monoid.. but how do we prove it as a submonoid?

Comment: Have you studied groups before? This is not too different from when you have to prove that some subset of a group is a subgroup. If not, what is the definition of submonoid? (I'll try to get you to figure out how to do it yourself instead of giving you the solution.)

Comment: i just started learning group this week.. and about submonoids, we define it as....Let (M,*,e) be a monoid and T⊆M , if T is closed under * and e ∈ T, where e is the identity element the T is said to be the submonoid of M

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll write down an answer with some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a monoid with. For simplicity, I will write the operation by contatenation (as we do for multiplication), and the unit of $M$ as $1$. A **submonoid** of $M$ is a subset $A\subseteq M$ satisfying the following two properties:

1. $1\in A$ (that is, $A$ contains the unit of $M$);
2. If $x,y\in A$, then $xy\in A$ as well.

So the question is asking you to prove that the set of idempotents of $M$ is a submonoid of $M$. There are again some definitions to unravel here: An element $e$ of $M$ is **idempotent** if $ee=e$.

Good, now we have all definitions spelled out just in terms of the monoid structure.

Let $E=\left\{e\in M:ee=e\right\}$, be the set of idempotents of $M$. To check that $E$ is a submonoid of $M$, we need to verify that $E$ satisfies properties $1$ and $2$ above.

1. To check that $1\in E$, we need to verify that satisfies the property defining $E$, that is, $11=1$. Do you see why this is true?
2. Take arbitrary elements $x,y\in E$. Then, **by hypothesis**, $xx=x$ and $yy=y$, and $xy=yx$, because $M$ is commutative. We need to verify that $xy\in E$ as well, that is, that $(xy)(xy)=(xy)$. Let us try to write down a sequence of identities starting with the first term and ending with the second one. I'll start for you: By associativity of the operation:
   $$(xy)(xy)=x(yx)y$$
   can you use the hypotheses above to rewrite $x(yx)y$ as $xy$?

Comment: (xy)(xy)=x(yx)y=x(xy)y=(xx)(yy)=xy ...?

Comment: @Rejani Perfect